# "mount" a PostgreSQL database from files not Backup

Tags: postgresql

I've been given a project to extract data from a PostgreSQL database. I've no previous experience with PostgreSQL but the project I have is to bug fix existing code, so all the logic to connect to the engine and get data is already in place.

The problem I have is the database has been given to me in the form of the folders and files straight from the source HDD, not a backup (which isn't going to happen so "Get the customer to give you a backup instead isn't an option here).

The folders also contained the actual PostgreSQL binaries so I looked a the version (9.4.14) and downloaded the nearest (9.4.18) from the PostgreSQL site and installed it. Now all I have to do is some how is to get it to look at my given data files.

I tried the obvious of copying the contents of the data folder into the installed data folder but after the PostgreSQL service won't start.

I did find a option in the conf file:

```
#data_directory = 'ConfigDir'
```

I changed this to:

```
data_directory = 'C:\customer\data'
```

But again the service won't start after this.

Comment: If the database was copied while PostgreSQL was stopped, it is good. If not, you'll have data corruption. Your procedure looks correct. Please give more details (operating system, how you installed PostgreSQL, the exact steps you did). Try to start PostgreSQL manually with `pg_ctl start -D /path/to/data/directory` and tell us the error messages you get and what you find in the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data directory used by the service is defined through the service command line which overwrites any property defined in `postgresql.conf`.

You need to re-create the service in order to change the data directory, e.g.:

Remove the service:

```
pg_ctl -unregister -N postgresql-9.1
```

`postgresql-9.1` is the "real" name of the service, not the "Display Name". You can see that in the properties of the service inside the "services" app.

Then re-create the service with the correct data directory:

```
pg_ctl -register -D -D c:\customer\data -N postgresql-9.1
```

Another way of "debugging" startup errors in Windows, is to start Postgres from the command line (not through the service) because some errors during startup are not logged in the Postgres logfile but they are displayed on the command line. You can do that with e.g.:

```
pg_ctl  start -D c:\customer\data`
```

---

If the `bin` directory is not in your `PATH` you need to specify the full path to it on the command line, e.g.: `c:\Postgres9.1\bin\pg_ctl`